# Reply button from Social Customer Service not appears in the Case

Tags: case, service-cloud-console, social-customer-service

I have enabled Social Customer Service and installed starter pack and noticed that the buttons "reply" and "follow" does not appears. What can be the problem? In the image the example of trailhead.

[image]